# Nagios stats about host-group and service-group

Tags: nagios, stat

I'm wondering if it's possible to get the stats and status of host-groups and service-groups with a command like we can get stats and status about hosts and services with the command nagiostats ?

Or can we filter the nagiostats results (by specified hosts or services) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get host-groups, service groups and all other data using NAGIRA API. Without it i believe you will have to parse the nagios output files such as cache.dat and status.dat etc to get this info.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to take a look at that.